# Leak on SiddhiRuntime

Tags: java, siddhi

I'm using Siddhi 5.1.15 and Java.
I few days I have done some dump and I have notice that my dominator and possible leak.

[MAT Analizer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTmR9.png)

[MAT Analizer2 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHmKP.png)

[MAT Analizer2 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRf0F.png)

```
I am concerned about how the .ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor grows for a simple application. Can you help me understand where I'm wrong, and how can I optimize my application?
    
    @App:name('LaraStream')
    @App:description('Gestione Degli SmartObject')
    @App:statistics("Is_Enabled")
    
    @source(type='lara:akka', spid='23434',tenid='398398398',projectuuid='2003333')
    define stream SmartObjectStream (partID string,topicID string,partnerID string,tenID string,sourceID string,deviceID string, objectID string, sensorID string, instanceID string, timestampS string,timestampL long,value double, metadata string);
    
    @sink(type='lara:mqtt' , topic='l/lara/hello')
    define stream NotifyStream (topicID string, partnerID string,tenID string,sourceID string,deviceID string, objectID string, sensorID string,instanceID string,timestampS string,timestampL long, value double, totalValue double, averageValue double, countValue long);
    
    @purge(enable='true', interval='10 sec', idle.period='1 hour')
    @info(name = 'Partion-Query')
    partition with (partID of SmartObjectStream)
    begin
    @info(name='Aggregation-query')
    from SmartObjectStream#window.time(1 hour) 
    select  topicID, partnerID,tenID,sourceID,deviceID, objectID, sensorID, instanceID,timestampS,timestampL, value, sum(value) as totalValue, avg(value) as averageValue, count() as countValue 
    insert into #EventInStream;
    
    @info(name = 'Notify-Events')
    from every (e1=#EventInStream[timestampL > 0])
    select e1[last].topicID, e1[last].partnerID,e1[last].tenID,e1[last].sourceID,e1[last].deviceID, e1[last].objectID, e1[last].sensorID, e1[last].instanceID,e1[last].timestampS,e1[last].timestampL, e1[last].value, e1[last].totalValue, e1[last].averageValue, e1[last].countValue insert into NotifyStream;
end
```